# Change graphic context in SWT application

Tags: eclipse, swt

I have a simple application written with SWT. I'm geting `GC` from `SWT.Paint` event. In my main canvas I've added a `MouseMove`listener so some text will be displayed over specified area if mouse is in area.

I would like to remove text from `GC` after the mouse is not anymore over area. I didnt find any mention about removing drawn objects from GC or replacing GC with new one.

Could you tell me how can I can achive such result? There is no other access to `GC` object than through `SWT.Paint` event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elements like text of lines that are drawn on a GC cannot be removed. Even though, a GC has methods to draw text and lines, etc, these methods merely transform the shapes into pixels and that is all a GC knows of.

Therefore your application should maintain a *model* that allows to position text and remove once placed text elements. Whenever the model changes, the canvas should be refreshed with `canvas.redraw()` which sends an `SWT.Paint` event. Your paint listener can then examine the model and paint text accordingly.

The article [Graphics Context - Quick on the draw](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-graphics/SWT_graphics.html) has further details on SWTs graphics context.

Answer (score -1):

Add MouseTrackListener and control mouse enter and leave canvas

```
MouseTrackListener mtl = new MouseTrackAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseEnter(MouseEvent e) {
        // add your PaintListener here
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExit(MouseEvent e) {
    // remove PaintListener here    
    }
};
canvas.addMouseTrackListener(mtl)
```